# Issues with format

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have been experiencing issues with formatting. This simple issue has turned to be a bit complicated; I am receiving errors because my code is improperly formatted. I tried, selecting my code, then right click -> source - > format but that has been unsuccessful has well.

Below is the complete code,

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);
           save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
            String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
            if(!picturePath.equals(""))
            {
               ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            }        

            Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
            buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                }
            });        
            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Locate the image in res > 
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
                    // Convert it to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    Object image = null;
                    try {
                        String path = null;
                        image = readInFile(path);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Create the ParseFile
                    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", (byte[]) image);
                    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                    file.saveInBackground();

                    // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
                    ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

                    // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                    imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");


                    // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                    imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

                    // Create the class and the columns
                    imgupload.saveInBackground();

                    // Show a simple toast message

                    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); 
                    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue); 

                    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

                @Override 
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, 
                  boolean fromUser) { 
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                 seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
                } 

                @Override 
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                } 

                @Override 
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                } 
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }

    private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] data = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
        int bytes_read;
        while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
        }
        input_stream.close();
        return buffer.toByteArray();

    }
}
```

In particular, at the following lines:

```
@Override 
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
} 
});
}}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: What IDE did you use?

Comment: The IDE I use was eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking over your code it doesn't seem like your open and close braces match up everywhere. I would step through all of them individually and make sure that the open braces match up with the correct close bracket. For example.

At the end of the line you speak about:

```
onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } }); }}
```

you haven't closed your onclicklistener for your "save" button with a corresponding }); and you also have }}, that is also bad formatting.

Depending on your IDE (I know Android Studio and Eclipse do this) if you click on one brace it will show you where the corresponding close brace is. Other than that, nothing seems wrong with your code.

EDIT: See below for the fixed version of your code:

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
        if (!picturePath.equals("")) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }


        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Locate the image in res > 
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                Object image = null;
                try {
                    String path = null;
                    image = readInFile(path);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create the ParseFile
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", (byte[]) image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground();

                // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
                ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

                // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");


                // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

                // Create the class and the columns
                imgupload.saveInBackground();

                // Show a simple toast message

                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue);

                seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                                  boolean fromUser) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                        seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and explanation. I have just closed the oncliclistener, but the issues still remains.

Comment: See my edit for the fixed code. If this answer helped you please accept it.